# AWS RDS restored from snapshot is super slow with the composite index

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot, composite-index

So I have 2 tables, each of them is 25GB.

Table t1 has an index on a single column and t2 has a composite index.
All my queries are simple query making use of the index.

my t2 table

```
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `uid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  KEY `composite` (`uid`,`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

my query

```
explain select * from t2 where uid between 1 and 10000 and time between 11 and 10000000;
```

the explain result:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | q3    | NULL       | range | composite     | composite | 18      | NULL | 2548 |    11.11 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.19 sec)
```

The strange thing that I observed is that when I restore a database from the snapshot, the t2 would become super slow with 3000 latency but the t1 would become normal(with 100 latency) after around 5 minutes.

I understand the snapshot is stored in s3. But why t1 works fine but t2 is super slow?

UPDATE: I checked manually and found out the composite index is there. I suspect that my composite index for t2 doesn't even work.

And I don't think it's the issue of memory buffer, otherwise, the t2 should become normal after my 5 minutes intensive query test.

Comment: Short answer: well deleted tables data will be removed from the innodb db buffer.. new created/restored tables will not be in the innodb buffer (directly) meaning it's a disk i/o based not memory i/o based

Comment: to manually warm up the innodb buffer i believe it was possible with `SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY <primary_key>` or it was `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table> ORDER BY <primary_key>`  the select query might be better/faster as you dont't flood your MySQL client with data.

Comment: And when you done that add `innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown = ON, innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup = ON.` to the config for automatic warmup.

Comment: @RaymondNijland hi, Raymond, why do you think it's the issue of memory buffer? Sorry if I didn't make it clear before, I would do a 5 minutes intensive query to warm up, the warmup only works for t1 but not for t2.

Comment: well to broad to explain buffer pool also has a [Buffer Pool LRU Algorithm](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) and also a size.

Comment: yes i understand the buffer would be cleared time to time. But even without buffer, the latency shouldn't be that slow

Comment: Also the table structures might also impact the server performance.. ideally you should post the table structurs with `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question and the queries you are using and the `EXPLAIN query` output.. Otherwise we can't help you and you are on you own.. Also when in doubt contact amazon if you think the server is (heavy) underperforming.

Comment: The most likely cause is that an EBS volume restored from a snapshot is lazily loaded. There are other questions about that on this site, or you can review the [EBS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html).

Comment: @RaymondNijland I just provided all information. thx!

Comment: yea just like i expected there is a text column, which requires extra disk i/o to be fetched as text is stored separated from the other table data.(other pages)

Comment: @RaymondNijland i see... how would you suggest me to deal with it then? besides  setting the automatic warmup.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: What's the `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: Ping ping @RickJames never got his answer :)

Comment: @RaymondNijland 's suggested warm up query worked for me; after running it; query time for selects improved immediately!